# Mixing std::move() and std::thread won't compile

Tags: c++, c++11

Having code as follows:

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

class A
{
  void foo(int&& arg) const {}

  void boo() const 
  {
    int value(0);
    std::thread t(&A::foo, this, std::move(value));
    t.join();
  }

};

int main()
{
  A a;
  return 0;
}
```

MS Visual Studio 2012 (toolset v110) gives next error:

> error C2664: '_Rx
>   std::_Pmf_wrap<_Pmf_t,_Rx,_Farg0,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,>::operator ()(const _Wrapper &,_V0_t) const' : cannot convert parameter
>   2 from 'int' to 'int &&'

What's that? Can't we use move semantics through threads?

Comment: For what it's worth, this does compile in g++ and clang.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is bug in VS. You can see this:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/737812

//
Opened: 4/19/2012 8:58:36 PM, hmm :)

And workaround from theirs page:

> You can use `std::ref`, but it's not the same.

Closed as fixed, so probably you need to use never tools or use 'workaround'.

Comment: thank you! it took me three years to encounter with such thing

Comment: [std::thread constructor doesn't handle movable object](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729886/std-thread-constructor-doesnt-handle-movable-object) says that it got fixed in VS 2015 RTM